# .Net Unicode character mapping

Tags: .net, fonts, glyph

Let's assume we have following two classes

```
Typeface
GlyphTypeface
```

We can create instance of `GlyphTypeface` class via `Typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface` method,
but before creating object for `GlyphTypeface` we create object of `Typeface` using following 
constructor

```
public Typeface(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch);
```

When we create object fontFamily we hard coded fontName(for example Calibri). 
.Net auto populated property `CharacterToGlyphMap` of `GlyphTypeface`  for glyph indexes.

I want to know population if the `CharacterToGlyphMap` depends on fontName (calibri)?
Actual problem is that when we use fontname(calibri) and try to get the value from `CharacterToGlyphMap` by hindi symbols we get 'an error key not found'.